# how to change the default readout message "Thanks for trying our documentation. Enjoy" to a custom message

Tags: twilio, voice

I'm new to Twilio. I have configured to make outbound call and the call url is `http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml` which readout a message

> Thanks for trying our documentation. Enjoy

How to change it to some other custom message?

Answer (score -2):

The quickest way is to use a Twimlet.

You are also able to use [inline TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls), with TwiML being explained best here, [TwiML For Programmable Voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml).

[What is a Simple Message](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/message)